# Dynamic Array show if not null behavior

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dynamic

I have a dynamic array that is used to display deposits called depositInfo, and an element called depositCards to render the array dynamically.

```
  const depositInfo = [];
  const depositCard = (card, index) => {
    if (JSON.stringify(depositInfo[index][0].tsR) != null) {
      return JSON.stringify(depositInfo[index][0].tsR);
    } else
      return (<Text>Values Null</Text>)
  }
```

The result i get on the site is:

```
nullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull
```

Once the data is actually retrieved into the array, the correct numbers are displayed instead of null (but say there are actually 3 elements that are not null, 3 will return not null and the rest will be null). Why is this line below not working?

```
if (JSON.stringify(depositInfo[index][0].tsR) != null)
```

I have tried different variations of

```
if (JSON.stringify(depositInfo[index][0].tsR) != null)
```

But am still getting the same results.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(null)` results in `'null'` (a string containing the word null) and not `null`. Therefore, your test will always be "true".

Comment: @crashmstr Exactly what i was looking for, thank you!